# How to interface android application with windows application running on pc

Tags: c#, android, winforms

I need to pass the input from an android phone to a windows application written in C#. 
To be specific, image taken from android device should be able to go to my application in PC.
I have no idea where to start with. I tried to google it out but no use.
Can anybody help me please. PC and phone may be connected through bluetooth.

thank you

Answer (score 0):

I think the best you can go with is sockets. Create a socket in your c# application and connect to it from the android device. This should work if they are both in the same network.

Otherwise you can try bluetooth to connect the devices.